# Best solution to keep multiple processes open at the same time?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I'm developing a python script, this script needs to read device events via api, so I need to maintain a flow connection with each device and read their events at all times, when the events arrive, I'll save them in the database. The problem is that there are 4500 devices for monitoring, so I have to keep 4500 stream connections open, I believe it is impossible with a server running my script to do this, as it will not have enough memory and cpu for so many processes. I'm using Multiprocessing Library Pool to test with few devices and it's working, but 4500 devices I find it impossible. Does anyone have a tip or advice to solve this problem?

Comment: `as it will not have enough memory and cpu`, hmm. How much RAM & CPU load per process? Are the processed I/O bound? Can you load balance, distribute `device` streams accross multiple machines?

Comment: You must first optimize the processing for each device, as both memory and CPU usage can potentially reach up to 4,500 times. It is not advisable to skip this step and try to solve this problem by simply changing the way you use multiprocessing.

Comment: I'm checking with the client what the server configuration is. I don't see any other way to do this script without using poll from multiprocessing, is this the best approach in this case?